# What is the crafting recipe for these taunts?

Tags: team-fortress-2

On team fortress 2 I just finished a test run for the compound bow for sniper. Well I tried to see if I could test run taunts. Sadly, you can't. But I noticed that a lot of the taunts are craftable. What are the crafting recipes for the rancho relaxo, flipping awesome, Rock Paper Scissors, conga and the square dance?

Answer (score 4):

You cannot use taunts in crafting, and you cannot get them as a result from crafting. Taunts are apparently capable of having craft numbers, and they apparently can come in "craftable" and "uncraftable" varieties, but there are no crafting recipies that have them as either a component or a result.

Comment: Then what is the deal with Mann co store saying it IS craftable

Comment: If I get your meaning correctly, "craftable" in that context means "is allowed to be used as a crafting ingredient", whether there exist crafting recipies that accept it as an ingredient or not.

Comment: Ok then that is just down right misleading.

Comment: Since this was bumped by community: Craftable is the default unless an item is explicitly marked as uncraftable.

Answer (score 1):

The Mann Co. Store reflects attributes/properties that are in the item schema. The item schema is basically an XML file that dictates where items can be used (crafting recipes, strangifiers, killstreak kits, etc).

Taunts are listed as 'craftable' in the item schema, however there are no crafting recipes for it. This means that while they cannot be a crafting *result*, they can still be used as a crafting *ingredient*. Taunts have very limited uses as a crafting ingredient since no specific recipes call for them, but Halloween Transmute is one recipe where they can be used.

The wording behind it is certainly misleading. The lack of crafting recipes for taunts is certainly by design though, as they can only be obtained by methods involving real-world currency (purchase, crates, or trading with someone who bought or unboxed it). The only exception is the Director's Vision taunt, which is obtained by completing the achievement *Star Of My Own Show*.